# Using Sums in Array Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array that consists of static cells in variable workbooks. 
When I copy them to the active workbook, there are fewer cells than were in the original array. So 39 cells in the array being rolled into 33 cells as an example.
Is there a way to sum the cells in the array like this?
`Array("C6" + "C7","C8","C9")`?
Example Sheets

Source from external workbook:

[image]

Result in active workbook:
[image]

What I actually want result to look like:
[image]
In my code I am trying to modify the cls array so `"C6"` would be `"C6+C7"` or something:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

Dim B1 As Workbook
Dim B2 As Workbook
Dim S1 As Range
Dim cls As Variant, LR As Long, i As Long

Set B1 = ActiveWorkbook

cls = Array("C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C10", "C11", "C12", "G12")
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx*;*.xlsm*;*.xlsa*;*.xm*"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        Set B2 = ActiveWorkbook
        Set S1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source sheet (select any cell)", Title:="Source sheet", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
        With B1.Sheets("Sheet2")
            For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
                .Range("C4").Offset(, i).Value = S1.Parent.Range(cls(i)).Value
            Next i
            .Range("C4:K4").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
        B2.Close False
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that demonstrates four variations of describing ranges of cells to be used in a sum operation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sumComplex()
    Dim i As Long, cls As Variant

    cls = Array("A1:A3", "B2,B4,B6", "C2:C3,C5", "D4")

    With Worksheets("sheet9")
        For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
            Debug.Print Application.Sum(.Range(cls(i)))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

```
'results
 6 
 12 
 20 
 99
```

This could be applied to your code in the following manner.

```
cls = Array("C3", "C4", "C5", "C6:C7", "C10", "C11", "C12,G12")
...
    With B1.workSheets("Sheet2")
        For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
            if S1.Parent.Range(cls(i)).count > 1 then
                .Range("C4").Offset(0, i).Value = _
                    application.sum(S1.Parent.Range(cls(i)))
            else
                .Range("C4").Offset(0, i).Value = S1.Parent.Range(cls(i))
            end if
        Next i
        .Range("C4").resize(1, i).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
```

Comment: tbh, I found your example code incomplete and a bit confusing; hence my generalized response. Best guess would be `.Range("B7").Offset(, i) = Application.Sum(TargetSummSheet.Parent.Range(cls(i)))`

Comment: How is the current code incomplete?     Can you modify your generalized response to fit the question?    I am trying to copy multiple cells to a defined row and some of the cells need to be summed. Can I turn part of the cls variables into  another variable? `arrVar = "C6"+"C7"` or something?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Without an mcve, there is simply too much guesswork.

Comment: Look at my response above. Anyone can take the code and sample data then step through the code to achieve the provided results. Now look at your question and note what is missing.

Comment: I modified my question to show what I want. I also reduced the code to make it more legible.

Comment: Thanks for this. Modified your code and got it working. One question: Why doesn't `C12+G12` work but `C12,G12` does?

Comment: Well, actually, it should work but that is not correct syntax for a sum function. In fact `c12+g12` could also be used as `evaluate(cls(i))`

Comment: ... and `Range("C12+G12")` is not a valid reference.